# Oracle Compound Join Predicate Causes Row Estimate to be Incorrect

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, predicate, sql-execution-plan, cardinality-estimation

In the example below Oracle's optimizer's estimated rows is incorrect by two orders of magnitude.  How do I improve the estimated rows?

Table `A` has rows with numbers 1 through 1,000 for each of the 10 letters A through J.

Table `C` has 100 copies of table `A`.

So, table `A` has a cardinality of 10K and table C has a cardinality of 1M.

A given single-valued predicate on the number in table `A` will yield 1/1000 of the rows in table `A` (same for table `C`).

A given single-valued predicate on the letter in table `A` will yield 1/10 of the rows in table `A` (same for table `C`).

Setup script.

```sql
drop table C;
drop table A;

create table A
  ( num NUMBER
  , val VARCHAR2(3 byte)
  , pad CHAR(40 byte)
  )
;
 
insert /*+ append enable_parallel_dml parallel (auto) */
  into A (num, val, pad)
  select mod(level-1, 1000) +1
       , chr(mod(ceil(level/1000) - 1, 10) + ascii('A'))
       , ' '
    from dual
    connect by level <= 10*1000
;
 
create table C
  ( id NUMBER
  , num NUMBER
  , val VARCHAR2(3 byte)
  , pad CHAR(40 byte)
  )
;
 
insert /*+ append enable_parallel_dml parallel (auto) */
  into C (id, num, val, pad)
  with
    "D1" as
    ( select /*+ materialize */ null from dual connect by level <= 100 --320
    )
    , "D" as
      ( select /*+ materialize */
               level                                           rn
             , mod(level-1, 1000) + 1                          num
             , chr(mod(ceil(level/1000) - 1, 10) + ascii('A')) val
             , ' '                                             pad
          from dual
          connect by level <= 10*1000
          order by 1 offset 0 rows
      )
    select rownum      id
         , num         num
         , val         val
         , pad         pad
      from "D1", "D"
;
commit;
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(OwnName => null, TabName => 'A', cascade => true);
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(OwnName => null, TabName => 'C', cascade => true);
```

Consider the explain plan to the following query.

```sql
select *
  from A
       join C
         on A.num = C.num
            and A.val = C.val
 where A.num = 1
       and A.val = 'A'
;
```

```sql
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |   100 |  9900 |  2209   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |      |   100 |  9900 |  2209   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |     1 |    47 |    23   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| C    |   100 |  5200 |  2185   (1)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - access("A"."NUM"="C"."NUM" AND "A"."VAL"="C"."VAL")
   2 - filter("A"."NUM"=1 AND "A"."VAL"='A')
   3 - filter("C"."NUM"=1 AND "C"."VAL"='A')
```

The row cardinality of each step makes sense to me.

ID=2 --> (1/1,000) * (1/10) *    10,000 = 1

ID=3 --> (1/1,000) * (1/10) * 1,000,000 = 100

ID=1 --> 100 is correct.  Predicates in ID=2 and ID=3 are the same, every row from ID=2 will have one and only one match in the row source from ID=3.

Now consider the explain plan to the slightly modified query below.

```sql
select *
  from A
       join C
         on A.num = C.num
            and A.val = C.val
 where A.num in(1,2)
       and A.val = 'A'
;
```

```sql
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     2 |   198 |  2209   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |      |     2 |   198 |  2209   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |     2 |    94 |    23   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| C    |   200 | 10400 |  2185   (1)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - access("A"."NUM"="C"."NUM" AND "A"."VAL"="C"."VAL")
   2 - filter("A"."VAL"='A' AND ("A"."NUM"=1 OR "A"."NUM"=2))
   3 - filter("C"."VAL"='A' AND ("C"."NUM"=1 OR "C"."NUM"=2))
```

The row cardinality of each step ID=2 and ID=3 makes sense to me, but now ID=1 is incorrect by two orders of magnitude.

ID=2 --> (1/1,000)(1/10) *    10,000 = 1

ID=3 --> (1/1,000)(1/10) * 1,000,000 = 100

ID=1 --> The optimizer's estimate is two orders of magnitude different from the actual.

Adding unique and foreign constraints and extended statistics did not improve the estimated row counts.

```sql
create unique index IU_A on A (num, val);
alter table A add constraint UK_A unique (num, val) rely using index IU_A enable validate;
alter table C add constraint R_C foreign key (num, val) references A (num, val) rely enable validate;
create index IR_C on C (num, val);
select dbms_stats.create_extended_stats(null,'A','(num, val)') from dual;
select dbms_stats.create_extended_stats(null,'C','(num, val)') from dual;
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(OwnName => null, TabName => 'A', cascade => true);
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(OwnName => null, TabName => 'C', cascade => true);
```

```sql
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |      |     2 |   198 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                  |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                 |      |     2 |   198 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INLIST ITERATOR             |      |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| A    |     2 |    94 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | IU_A |     2 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN            | IR_C |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | C    |     1 |    52 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   5 - access(("A"."NUM"=1 OR "A"."NUM"=2) AND "A"."VAL"='A')
   6 - access("A"."NUM"="C"."NUM" AND "C"."VAL"='A')
       filter("C"."NUM"=1 OR "C"."NUM"=2)
```

What do I need to do to make the estimated rows better match reality?

Using Oracle Enterprise Edition 19c.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
After ensuring the most recent optimizer_features_enable was used and modifying one of the predicates, we still have an explain plan whose estimated row count is short by two orders of magnitude.

ID=6 ought to have an estimated rows of 100.  It seems it is applying the predicate factor twice.  Once for the access and again for the filter.

```sql
select /*+ optimizer_features_enable('19.1.0') */
       *
  from A
       join C
         on A.num = C.num
            and A.val = C.val
 where A.num in(1,2)
       and A.val in('A','B')
;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id  | Operation                              | name | rows  | Bytes | cost (%CPU)| time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | select statement                       |      |     4 |   396 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  nested LOOPS                          |      |     4 |   396 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   nested LOOPS                         |      |     4 |   396 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INLIST ITERATOR                     |      |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     table access by index ROWID BATCHED| A    |     4 |   188 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      index range scan                  | IU_A |     4 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |    index range scan                    | IR_C |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |   table access by index ROWID          | C    |     1 |    52 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
--------------------------------------------------- 
   5 - access("A"."NUM"=1 or "A"."NUM"=2)
       filter("A"."VAL"='A' or "A"."VAL"='B')
   6 - access("A"."NUM"="C"."NUM" and "A"."VAL"="C"."VAL")
       filter(("C"."NUM"=1 or "C"."NUM"=2) and ("C"."VAL"='A' or "C"."VAL"='B'))
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. On my 19c Enterprise Edition database, I get 200 rows for the second explain plan by default. What's your full version, based on `SELECT version_full FROM product_component_version`? (I'm on 19.3.0.0.0 on Windows) Also, try the advanced option for explain plans and see if you see anything "weird" in the Outline Data or other sections: `explain plan for select ...; select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'advanced'));`

Comment: Thank you.  19.13.0.0.0 on RedHat.  The Outline Data showed ``optimizer_features_enabled`` of 11.2.0.2.  Changing this to 11.2.0.3 fixed it.  So it was some optimizer feature between 11.2.0.2 and 11.2.0.3.  However, with only the ``IU_A`` index and using a predicate of ``A.num in(1,2) and A.val in('A','B')`` we still have a incorrect row estimates even when using ``/*+ optimizer_features_enabled('19.1.0') */``.